# How to train a combination of models in Flux?

Tags: neural-network, julia

I am trying to build a deep learning model in julia. I have two models m1 and m2 which are neural networks. Here is my code:

```
using Flux

function even_mask(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    weight_mask = zeros(s1, s2)
    weight_mask[2:2:s1,:] = ones(Int(s1/2), s2)
    return weight_mask
end

function odd_mask(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    weight_mask = zeros(s1, s2)
    weight_mask[1:2:s1,:] = ones(Int(s1/2), s2)
    return weight_mask
end

function even_duplicate(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    x_ = zeros(s1, s2)
    x_[1:2:s1,:] = x[1:2:s1,:]
    x_[2:2:s1,:] = x[1:2:s1,:]
    return x_
end

function odd_duplicate(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    x_ = zeros(s1, s2)
    x_[1:2:s1,:] = x[2:2:s1,:]
    x_[2:2:s1,:] = x[2:2:s1,:]
    return x_
end

function Even(m)
    x -> x .+ even_mask(x).*m(even_duplicate(x))
end

function InvEven(m)
    x -> x .- even_mask(x).*m(even_duplicate(x))
end

function Odd(m)
    x -> x .+ odd_mask(x).*m(odd_duplicate(x))
end

function InvOdd(m)
    x -> x .- odd_mask(x).*m(odd_duplicate(x))
end

m1 = Chain(Dense(4,6,relu), Dense(6,5,relu), Dense(5,4))
m2 = Chain(Dense(4,7,relu), Dense(7,4))

forward = Chain(Even(m1), Odd(m2))
inverse = Chain(InvOdd(m2), InvEven(m1))

function loss(x)
    z = forward(x)
    return 0.5*sum(z.*z)
end

opt = Flux.ADAM()

x = rand(4,100)

for i=1:100
    Flux.train!(loss, Flux.params(forward), x, opt)
    println(loss(x))
end
```

The forward model is a combination of m1 and m2. I need to optimize m1 and m2 so I could optimize both forward and inverse models. But it seems that params(forward) is empty. How could I train my model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think plain functions can be used as layers in Flux. You need to use the `@functor` macro to add the extra functionality to collect parameters: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/basics/#Layer-helpers-1

In your case, rewriting `Even`, `InvEven`, `Odd` and `InvOdd` like this should help:

```
struct Even
    model
end

(e::Even)(x) = x .+ even_mask(x).*e.model(even_duplicate(x))

Flux.@functor Even
```

After adding this definition,

```
Flux.params(Even(m1))
```

Should return a non-empty list

**EDIT**

An even simpler way to implement `Even` and friends is to use the built-in [SkipConnection](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/layers/#Flux.SkipConnection) layer:

```
 Even(m) = SkipConnection(Chain(even_duplicate, m),                         
                          (mx, x) -> x .+ even_mask(x) .* mx)
```

I suspect this is a version difference, but with Julia 1.4.1 and Flux v0.10.4, I get the error `BoundsError: attempt to access () at index [1]` when running your training loop, I need to replace the data with

```
x = [(rand(4,100), 0)]
```

Otherwise the loss is applied to each entry in the array `x`. since `train!` splats `loss` over `x`.

The next error `mutating arrays is not supported` is due to the implementation of `*_mask` and `*_duplicate`. These functions construct an array of zeros and then mutate it by replacing values from the input.

You can use [Zygote.Buffer](https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/latest/utils/#Zygote.Buffer) to implement this code in a way that can be differentiated.

```
using Flux
using Zygote: Buffer

function even_mask(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    weight_mask = Buffer(x)
    weight_mask[2:2:s1,:] = ones(Int(s1/2), s2)
    weight_mask[1:2:s1,:] = zeros(Int(s1/2), s2)
    return copy(weight_mask)
end

function odd_mask(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    weight_mask = Buffer(x)
    weight_mask[2:2:s1,:] = zeros(Int(s1/2), s2)
    weight_mask[1:2:s1,:] = ones(Int(s1/2), s2)
    return copy(weight_mask)
end

function even_duplicate(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    x_ = Buffer(x)
    x_[1:2:s1,:] = x[1:2:s1,:]
    x_[2:2:s1,:] = x[1:2:s1,:]
    return copy(x_)
end

function odd_duplicate(x)
    s1, s2 = size(x)
    x_ = Buffer(x)
    x_[1:2:s1,:] = x[2:2:s1,:]
    x_[2:2:s1,:] = x[2:2:s1,:]
    return copy(x_)
end

Even(m) = SkipConnection(Chain(even_duplicate, m),
                         (mx, x) -> x .+ even_mask(x) .* mx)

InvEven(m) = SkipConnection(Chain(even_duplicate, m),
                            (mx, x) -> x .- even_mask(x) .* mx)

Odd(m) = SkipConnection(Chain(odd_duplicate, m),
                        (mx, x) -> x .+ odd_mask(x) .* mx)

InvOdd(m) = SkipConnection(Chain(odd_duplicate, m),
                           (mx, x) -> x .- odd_mask(x) .* mx)

m1 = Chain(Dense(4,6,relu), Dense(6,5,relu), Dense(5,4))
m2 = Chain(Dense(4,7,relu), Dense(7,4))

forward = Chain(Even(m1), Odd(m2))
inverse = Chain(InvOdd(m2), InvEven(m1))

function loss(x, y)
    z = forward(x)
    return 0.5*sum(z.*z)
end

opt = Flux.ADAM(1e-6)

x = [(rand(4,100), 0)]

function train!()
    for i=1:100
        Flux.train!(loss, Flux.params(forward), x, opt)
        println(loss(x[1]...))
    end
end
```

At this point, you get to the real fun of deep networks. After one training step, the training diverges to `NaN` with the default learning rate. Reducing the initial training rate to 1e-6 helps, and the loss looks like it is decreasing.

Comment: Now I encountered this error: mutating arrays is not supported.